# The sequence of Category form messed up after inserting a new attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-attribute

I have a new attribute on category which is successfully installed and show on Category form. I planned to place it inside field group **Display Settings** which is successful. However, the sequence is messed up after installation.

Originally, the sequence was

- Currently Active
- Content
- Display Settings
- SEO
- ...

However after the attribute installation, the sequence changed to:

- Content
- Display Settings
- Currently Active
- SEO
- ...

So what's wrong with my installation? Here is my `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="display_settings">
        <field name="new_attr">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New label</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
               </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this is `etc/module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After some googling, I found that this function is not exist yet. There is a feature request on github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign to an existing fieldset, there are no solutions yet. However, you can have a workaround: Create a new fieldset and place it on the bottom of the form. So here is my modified `category_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="new_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Preorder</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- Rest of codes -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```